# CSV universal date format for all cultures

Tags: excel, csv

Is there universal date format for CSV that can be exported and easily translated in eg. Excel (with different cultures: US, UK, India etc.) ?

My system renders CSV file with US date format but Excel in other cultures can't handle it.

Maybe is possible to convert time from ticks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to format your date times as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`? This should then be recognised by Excel, regardless of culture.

Comment: Not always. My Excel recognize 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' as a string. My system locale is en-US, short date format = "dd MMM yyyy", long format = "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is No, if only because Excel itself may use either the 1900 or the 1904 date system. Your best bet may be to write a date/time index to .csv (today noon is `42005.5` in the more common 1900 date system) and have the end user format that to suit themselves.